# Update select2 with ajax post when you have php function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-modal, jquery-select2

I have a div called demclients which gets refreshed after the ajax post. If the ajax post runs, it creates a new client. I want to update the select field so I can select the new client that I just created.

```
    <div class="demclients">
     <div class="form-group">
           <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Klant zoeken</label>
           <div class="col-md-4">
                 <select id="allclients" style="width:300px;" name="client" required>
                     <?php foreach($user->getAllClients() as $klant) { ?>
                         <option value="<?= $klant['id']?>"><?= $klant['naam']?></option>
                     <?php } ?>
                 </select>
            </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

This code gets all the clients and shows them in the select field, which is what I want. But now I want to create a new client (which is done with the bootstrap modal).

```
$("form#createclient").submit(function (event) {

    var postForm = $('form#createclient').serialize() +             
        '&name=' + $('input[name=name]').val() +                      
        '&email=' + $('input[name=email]').val() +                    
        '&perms=' + $('input[name=rechten]').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "?page=clientmail",
        data: postForm,
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) {
            alert('Nieuwe klant aangemaakt');
            $('.demclients').load('?page=uploadoverview' +  ' .demclients');
        }
    });
    event.preventDefault();

});
```

So the submit function gets all information from the inputs and goes the the page clientmail to create a new client with this information, after that I update the information with:

```
`$('.demclients').load('?page=uploadoverview' +  ' .demclients');`.
```

In the header the select function gets called with this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#allclients").select2();
});
```

This code only runs once. I want to update the select while still keeping the drop down from the select2() function. I tried multiple methods of updating it like:

- putting select function in the demclients div that updates after ajax
  success
- using select2("destroy") and then calling select2() again to make it update

But I just can't get it to update the select field while keeping the drop down from the select2() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use success callback of the load method because select2 should only be called when the load is done and new html is available in the page

```
success: function (result) {
            alert('Nieuwe klant aangemaakt');
            $('.demclients').load('?page=uploadoverview' +  ' .demclients', function(){
                 //success load event
                 $("#allclients").select2();
            });
        }
```

Comment: if its working and correct mark the answer as correct so others can take help from that. :)

Comment: can't do that just yet, but I will :)